# How can I divide a list of dataframes by a list of values?

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dataframe

(1) I have a list of 29 dataframes

(2) I have a list of 29 values (all are int64)

I want to divide a column in the list from (1) with each in values of (2) -- they are in the correct order I want to divide them by

So for example, I want the 1st dataframe (all values in second column) in list 1 to be divided by the 1st value in list 2. I want the 2nd dataframe (all values in second column) in list 1 to be divided by 2nd value in list 2, and so on. E.g.:

This is the 6th dataframe in my first list:

```
    print(lst_1[6]):

   ITIS  q9036
0   7.0      7
1   2.0      5
2   1.0      4
3   3.0      3
4   5.0      2
```

This is the 6th integer in my second list, the value is 14:

```
print(lst_2[6]):

array([[14]], dtype=int64
```

So the result I want to acheive is something like this:

```
   ITIS  q9036  Total  Result
0   7.0      7  14     0.50
1   2.0      5  14     0.36     
2   1.0      4  14     0.29
3   3.0      3  14     0.21
4   5.0      2  14     0.14
```

I want to do this for all 29 dataframes for all 29 integers

Other things to note: the second column always has a different name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `zip` and [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), because each integer is in numpy array is necessary selecting by `[0][0]`:

```
dfs = [df.assign(total = i[0][0], 
                 result = df.iloc[:, -1] / i[0][0]) for i, df in zip(lst_2, lst_1)]
```

EDIT:

```
dfs = [df.assign(total = i[0][0], 
                 a = df.iloc[:, -1] / i[0][0])
        .rename(columns={'a':'{}_pct'.format(df.columns[-1])}) for i, df in zip(lst_2, lst_1)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work... "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1"

Comment: @DanONS - So need always divide second column?

Comment: @DanONS Solution is modified for divide by last column

Comment: That worked, beautiful code! How can I replace every column name "result" as "q9036_pct", "q9037_pct", "q9038_pct" and so on?

Comment: I did
[df.rename(columns = lambda x : str(x)+('_pct'), inplace = true) for df in dfs] but this adds pct for all, I just want to select it for the third column

Comment: @DanONS - I use trick - create column `a` and then rename it.

Comment: Thanks Jezrael you've been really helpful